# Counting numbers within a range

Tags: integer

Say I have two (positive) arbitrary decimal numbers, a and b.

I want to be able to count the number of integers that exist between a and b (a less than or equal to [Valid Integers] which is less than b) such that none of them exceed arbitrary number L. Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried loops and floors/ceilings but none of it is working the way I want it to and it's just getting to be messy.

Comment: Could you provide illustration data?

Comment: Not sure what this means. But say a=56.67 and b=67.8. Valid integers = 57 through 67 (11 numbers). But if L=62 or something, then valid integers = 57 through 62 (7 numbers).

Comment: Or, it could be a=5 and b=10, in which case valid integers = 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, (5 numbers) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple case is:

```
Count = Math.Min(Math.Max(a, b), L) - Math.Min(a,b);
```

However that has issues when `L` is less than both `a` and `b`, and doesn't cater for decimal numbers.

As such, give this a go:

```
int Count(double firstInput, double secondInput, double limit = int.MaxValue)
{
    int minInput = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Min(firstInput, secondInput));
    int maxInput = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Max(firstInput, secondInput));

    int L = (int)Math.Floor(limit);

    if (L<minInput)
        return 0;

    bool maxInputHasDecimals = (maxInput != Math.Max(firstInput, secondInput));
    return Math.Min(maxInput, L) - minInput + (maxInputHasDecimals ? 1 : 0);
}

Count(56.67, 67.8); // 11
Count(56.67, 67.8, 62.0); // 6
Count(56.67, 67.8, -3); // 0
Count(-10, -5, -3); // 5
Count(-10, -5, -7); // 3
Count(56.67, 67.0); // 10
```

Comment: Sorry, edited my initial post to clarify. a and b can be floats but the valid numbers within the range must be integers.

Comment: Updated. You're a bit inconsistent in your samples on whether you are inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: In what way? a and b can be anything as long as they are positive -- it's just looking for the integer values that exist between them (only caveat: valid integer can be equal to a if a is an integer itself). Valid integers must also be less than or equal to L (L will always be integral)

Comment: Your samples (5,10) is 5 digits (inclusive of lower, exclusive of upper) but your (57,62) sample seems to be inclusive of both?

Comment: In the (5,10) example, the lowest valid integer is 5 (it can equal a if a is an integer), highest valid is 9 (it's not 10 because it must be less than b). In the (a=56.67 and b=67.8) example, the valid integers are within this threshold because they are all greater than or equal to a and less than b (57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67) but not 56 because that's less than a, and not 68 because that's greater than b.

Comment: Try the updated +1 sample, I think it's what you are after. Apologies for the indentation, it doesn't seem to be working on this PC.

Comment: Right that's a different requirement. Updated.

Comment: I think that works (at least for what I've tried so far) thanks!

Comment: Not especially succinct, but should do the job.